# Transform a word into a unique identifier

Tags: string, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

My goal is to transform a word into a unique identifier (Number).

"WORD" => X(for instance)

But the Mathematical (or another approach) formula to be applied must be **determinist**, **transitive**, and **the character order matters**

For instance, let's define `transform` as the name of the Mathematical function like:

tranform("WORD") => X

**Rules/Goals:**

1. Must be deterministic:

   if `transform`("WORD") => X then the `transform` formula must always return X. So the `transform` formula cannot be the "Memory address of variables" for instance.
2. Transitive (Optional, It will be a nice to have for performance purposes)

   if `tranform`("WORD") => X
   then `tranform`("WORDS") => Y where Y > X.
3. The order matters

   `tranform`("WORD") must be different than `tranform`("ROWD")

**Any Idea/Approach?**

I have already try the folowing approach but it's not correct:

1. Ascii character code

   `transform`("WORD") = 87+79+82+68 = 316

   `transform`("ROWD") = 82+79+87+68 = 316

   So the rule 3 fails

Comment: sum up the products of each letters index with that letters number representation (A=1, B=2 etc).

Comment: Your edit is not what my answer describes. Base-128 is not simply adding up the numbers. Read up how base-n numbers work.

Comment: Your second requirement is impossible if your number is bounded, but the length of your strings are not.

There are more strings than numbers, so you'll have to map some strings to the same number, but then they can't be transitive.

Comment: @Rob ... Yes, I agree the transivity goal is perhaps impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ASCII, you can simply interpret every character as a number on [0, 128).

Then your words simply are numbers in base-128.

Your transitive requirement is underspecified, but this approach is at least transitive in word length.

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach but fails on rule nº3.

Comment: @Leonel No it does not. You  have not implemented my answer correctly.

Comment: Yes, You are right using a simple encoding algorithm solve my problem ... like base-128.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to generate a hashcode of sorts. Java's String implementation of `hashCode()` is fairly straightforward, so it wouldn't be difficult to implement something similar in another language.

The algorithm from the [Java API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()):

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

*s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string*

Comment: That's the better approach ... the transitivity goal is perhaps impossible to be achieved.

Comment: @Leonel "transitivity" doesn't really make sense in hashing, but you'll find that with this algorithm for many strings appending a character will in fact create a larger value. Longer strings will have larger values because of the addition over each char.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming the string to a base-n number is definitely the key (as described in the other answer). Here is how you can represent your `transform` function output:

I assume your transformation should be in the form of a decimal digit sequence. Also I assume that your characters are in the range of ASCII (128 total possibilities)

The key is to assign 3 digits for each of the letters in your initial string. The value of each three-digit position is set to the index of the letter (or character) from 0 to 127.

The transform function works like this:

```
transform(C1C2C3) = index[C1]index[C2]index[C3]
```

Where index returns a three digit sequence (i.e. 001, 020 or 120) that shows the position of the given character Cx. The results are concatenated to each other (not to be accumulated).

A sample would be:

transform("WORD") = 087079082068

Showing that the `transform` function covers all your rules is easy now.

Comment: Why it's always 0? ... sould not be instead tansform("WORD") = "087" + "179" + "282" + "368" = "087179282368"?

Comment: @Leonel ASCII for 'W','O','R','D' are 087, 079, 082, 068 respectively, this is probably quicker than 128-base transform but obviously consumes more memory.

Comment: As @Godsent said, this method uses more memory but a smart implementation of this using string processing (instead of arithmetic operations) may help get reach better performance. Note that padding with '0' helps you split the character codes with fixed length. It guarantees that each character will be transformed into three digits.